# Shopify in Android application

Tags: android, web-services, shopify

I am creating a android application for eCommerce website.

Here at server side, i am using Shopify's eCommerce software.

So how could i call web service generated through Shopify's eCommerce software.

I have make research on it.. 
I found one link also [link](http://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/java-android), but that demo is not running. 
I need one simple demo where how can i use shopify api in android application

Answer (score 1):

That Demo is working, I checked it today only. You can make a [webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and use the Java/Android Library to make the call.

Use this part to make your call (for more details check demo code or api page):

```
JsonDirectoryCredentialsStore store = new JsonDirectoryCredentialsStore(getFilesDir());
Credential emptyCredential = makeEmptyCredential(shopname);
store.saveCredential(emptyCredential);
APIAuthorization auth = new APIAuthorization(emptyCredential);
URI authRequest = auth.generateAuthRequest();
```

Pass this authRequest to a webview and set a webviewclient to handle redirections by shopify.

You can then set up a callback to your localhost in the dev store you created and connect to that with the emulator loopback interface **10.0.2.2** from the app to test. At least that's the most convenient way I found.

Comment: Which library included these classes APIAuthorization/JsonDirecotoryCredentialStore ?